# What is this clock next to my roblox username?

Tags: roblox

[image: a clock, I don’t understand what it is]

It’s a weird clock, I don’t understand it

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, whenever I see someone with the clock next to their name, I search them up and they always have Roblox premium.

Comment: I just realized this while playing bloxburg , someone told me in the chat and I checked it out for myself, I was surprised as it was true. It is probably another sign for premium or some bug, I’m not completely sure as I’m not an “expert”, for example, I had a premium and there was a clock beside my name, my friend also had premium at the time and she had the symbol too!!!! So I’m sorry if this isn’t the correct explanation, just a guess!! Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It means that it’s close towards your bday or it’s premium pending.

Answer (score -2):

I think it means that person just joined and may still be loading into the game. I'm not 100% sure, though.

Answer (score -2):

I encountered somebody that was in a game for a long time, and they had a clock on their name. I think it was some new afk mode but I'm not 100% sure.